# How to connect to VMs on VMware ESXi using physical connections

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, keyboard-video-mouse

My site is using the V sphere client to manage the VM,  and there is a KVM switch attached to the hosts(VMware ESXi, 7.0.2, 17867351). I'm wondering if I can use the KVM switch to access the VMs inside each host?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if I can use the KVM switch to access the VMs inside
> each host?

No.